# no viable overloaded '=' error, what may cause this?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods, abstract-class

**Note: I have uploaded my code here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1P8APG0I you can run it and reproduce the bug.**

I wrote an abstract `Character` class with is inherited by many classes like `Soldier` and `Medic`. also, I have a `Game` class which has:

```
mtm::Dimensions dimensions;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>> board;
```

**Important Note:** I can't change the code that's written above, so please consider that.

I need to write a copy c'tor for this class **Which makes a copy that isn't related at all to the previous one after the call is finished**, So I wrote:

```
Game::Game(const Game &other):dimensions(other.dimensions){
    int board_size = dimensions.getRow() * dimensions.getCol();
    for (int i = 0; i < board_size; ++i) {
        Character* copy = other.board[i]->clone();
        board[i]=*copy;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying:

> error: no viable overloaded '=' board[i]=*copy;

What does this mean and how may I fix it?

You may need the following implementation of clone over `Medic` class which inherits `Character`

```
Character * Medic::clone() const {
    return new Medic(*this);
}
```

---

**Update: I tried writing `=copy` instead of `=*copy` *but got exactly the same error*.**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @FredLarson https://onlinegdb.com/r1P8APG0I

Comment: You should try to contact [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13756099/daniel). They seem to be working on a very, very similar project and two heads are better than one.

Answer (score 4):

You are dereferencing a pointer here

```
board[i]=*copy;
```

If instead you are trying to construct a `std::shared_ptr` then create one using your raw pointer

```
board[i] = std::shared_ptr<Character>(copy);
```

which more concisely is just

```
board[i] = std::shared_ptr<Character>(other.board[i]->clone());
```

Comment: @FredLarson my code runs now, Thank you! please post this as answer with some more info

Comment: @FredLarson Good catch, thanks for pointing that out.